# Assign the value to the variable in Java

Tags: java

Need to write method snowForecast() and write lines of code to do (exactly) the following in order:

a. Define a boolean variable called snow, but do not initialise the variable.

b. Define an integer variable called temperature, in itialised to the value -5.

c. Define a boolean variable called rain, initialised to true

d. Assign to snow the value of the expression equivalent to saying it is raining and the temperature is less than 0.

e. Return the value of snow.

My code:

```
public class Q8 {

boolean snowForecast() {
    boolean snow; 
    int temperature=-5;
    boolean rain=true;
    if(rain==true&&temperature<0)
    return snow;
}
}
```

The problem is that I can't correctly assign the value to the "snow"..

Comment: In step "d" you need to do what was asked. You didn't assign anything to `snow`.

Comment: You've not assigned anything to snow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(rain && temperature < 0)
    snow = true;
```

But you also need to set `snow = false` by default, so:

```
public class Q8 {

boolean snowForecast() {
    boolean snow = false; 
    int temperature=-5;
    boolean rain=true;
    if(rain && temperature < 0)
        snow = true;
    return snow;
}
}
```

Right now, this is what your doing:

1) Initializing variables.

2) ONLY returning a VALUE if it will snow

Step two is where you go wrong. You should return `false` if there is not snow and `true` if there is snow. I think you're misunderstanding something very basic. I'm not sure what it is, but maybe you should look into a Java book or tutorial series.

Functions return a value. Boolean functions return `true` or `false`, with `return true` and `return false` respectively. You need to be returning SOMETHING, not just an empty variable (You actually can't return an empty variable in Java, but that's what you're trying to do).

An alternative way of writing it that might be easier for you to understand is this:

```
public class Q8 {

boolean snowForecast() {
    boolean snow = false; 
    int temperature=-5;
    boolean rain=true;
    if(rain && temperature < 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
}
```

**IMPORTANT** You really should learn at least the very basics of a language before posting on Stack Overflow. It makes it seem like you're not putting in any effort. As in, you just want us to write your code for you. Maybe add in what error message you're getting and why you're confused.